# How to use just 1 useState() for serveral states

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component that uses several states which are initialized in the same way useState(false), is there a way to combine all these states into a single useState(false)

```
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [fields, setFields] = useState(false);
  const [wrongImageType, setWrongImageType] = useState(false);
  const [aboutError, setAboutError] = useState(false);
  const [destinationError, setDestinationError] = useState(false)
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: cuzz i want to simplify the code and not having so many states tha do the same thing at the start @Toastrackenigma

Comment: Don't do this. There is no need to simplify the code when all the variables refers to diferents things.

Comment: But then you have to be extra careful when setting any particular state. You lose the ability to update one facet without triggering a change for everything

Comment: For what its worth, I think the code here already looks pretty simple, besides some of the variable names (what does `fields` mean? why is it a boolean?). Even if it was possible, I don't think changing states to all share an initialiser would simplify the code _at all_. It just adds a layer of indirection. What if now you want one of these to start as true? Do you now have to seperate that out?

Comment: Maybe it would be more productive to think about if you actually need to store this many seperate states --- could come of them be combined together, maybe, to store e.g. an enum value rather than a boolean? And maybe you could improve their names? I think that would help more.

Comment: i tought about it because i need to fill a form a check for each field to be filled before submiting it

Comment: HTML5 field validation will do that for you.

Comment: sorry im new at this i added the required prop to the input but i want show a message to the user saying that the field is required

Answer (score 3):

You can do like this

```js
const [states, setStates] = useState({ loading:false, fields:false, wrongImageType:false, aboutError:false, destinationError:false })
```

Update state like this

```js
setStates((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, loading: true }))
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the `useReducer` hook. That way, I can just slam properties to some state object and the reducer tidies it all up for me. It also makes it easy when I have to submit an object to an API, I just fling the entire `state` object to the server. So it's basically, "fetch data from the server, use form inputs to let the user update the values, fling the data back to the server when they click the save button."

```js
import React, {
  useReducer,
  useEffect
} from "react";

const initialState = {
  loading: false,
  fields: false,
  wrongImageType: false,
  aboutError: false,
  destinationError: false
};

const reducer = (prev, cur) => ({ ...prev, ...cur });

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  useEffect(() => {
    setState({
      loading: true
    });

    // fetch something or do something...

    setState({
      loading: false
    });

  }, []);

  return ({
    state.loading ? <> Loading </> : <>{state.something}</>
  });
}
```